# BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui fails to build because of ArrayMapKt

Tags: c#, maui, .net-8.0, google-vision

I'm building a MAUI app in .NET8 which will scan barcodes. I'm trying to integrate the GoogleVision library - BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui (8.0.0.1) and I'm getting an error which I have no idea how to solve. Any hints appreciated.

I see there already is a similar question on SO but no confirmed answer and I've tried the answers from there and they didn't work so I'm posting my question too.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
> Error JAVA0000    Error in
> C:\Users\UserX.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.2\buildTransitive\net7.0-android33.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class:
> Type androidx.collection.ArrayMapKt is defined multiple times:
> C:\Users\UserX.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.2\buildTransitive\net7.0-android33.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class,
> C:\Users\UserX.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx\1.2.0.9\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class
> Compilation failed java.lang.RuntimeException:
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to
> complete, origin:
> C:\Users\UserX.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.2\buildTransitive\net7.0-android33.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar
> androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class  at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:126)   at
> com.android.tools.r8.D8.main(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:5)
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException:
> Compilation failed to complete, origin:
> C:\Users\UserX.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.2\buildTransitive\net7.0-android33.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class
> at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_8.1.56.java:0)    at
> com.android.tools.r8.M.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:5)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:81)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:32)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:31)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.b(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:2)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:26)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:13)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:24)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:113)   ... 1 more Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Type
> androidx.collection.ArrayMapKt is defined multiple times:
> C:\Users\UserX.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.2\buildTransitive\net7.0-android33.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class,
> C:\Users\UserX.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx\1.2.0.9\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.O2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:21)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.O2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:26)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:44)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:10)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2056)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:6)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.graph.b4$a.e(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:7)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:58)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:9)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:8)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:29)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:17)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.D8.c(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:1)
> at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:28)
> ... 6 more  GoogleVision        1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me eventually was manually adding these two packages as direct project dependencies:

- `Xamarin.AndroidX.Core`
- `Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.Ktx`

Though I had problems forcing VS to install the second package and had to add a project reference in the `.csproj` file to force it to install it:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-android'">
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.Ktx">
    <Version>1.6.2.1</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, you need to add the following NuGet package to your project:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection.Jvm

I guess that it does not internally map this package, A bunch of Androidx packages have this problem so I am not surprised.